# Circular Referencing Packages - Python/Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, circular-dependency, graphene-python

During the course of a GraphQL implementation I'm finding myself making a lot of circular references to keep the packages modular. Consider the following folder structure.

```
project/
__init__.py

    graphql/
    __init__.py

        inputs/
        __init__.py

        company.py
        contact.py
```

*company.py*

```
import graphene

import graphql.inputs.contact


class CompanyInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    contacts = graphene.List(graphql.inputs.contacts.ContactInput)
    ...
```

*contact.py*

```
import graphene

import graphql.inputs.company


class ContactInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    company = graphql.inputs.company.CompanyInput()
```

I consistently get the Django error:

```
 ImportError at /api/v2/
 Could not import 'gql.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'company'.
```

Is this kind of circular referencing possible? Both contacts and companies need to be able to reference the input object class defined in the separate packages. This is so that graphql can take in inputs with with children and allow nested creation as well as allowing the input of an object with the creation of a parent.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to work around this issue. In *contact.py* I lazy loaded the CompanyInput using a lambda as follows:

```
import graphene

import graphql.inputs.company


class ContactInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    company = graphene.Field(lambda: graphql.inputs.company.CompanyInput)
```